# htaccess exclude CSS/JS/Images

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

This exclude CSS/JS/Images from original url. Anyone know how to solve this problem ?

.htacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

PHP:

```
$splitarray = explode('/',$_GET['uri']);
```

- I explode URL using PHP to get 2nd parameter and include that page to index.php

Comment: You *want* css/js/images to be routed through `index.php`?

Comment: Yes. because i used PHP include() function to connect header/content pages/footer. kind of a simple framework that use simple method :)

Comment: Also, are you sure the first 2 `RewriteRule` lines aren't supposed to be `RewriteCond`?

Comment: but those 2 lines doesn't do anything in my case... :/

Comment: Without those 2 lines, you should be routing all requests, including css/js/images, through `index.php`

Comment: When i removed those 2 lines still the same problem apear. but after i remvoed RewriteEngine on line, images working properly but URI not passing to index.php

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(js|css|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So this will route through `index.php` if the request isn't for an existing directory and, the request isn't for an existing file OR the request isn't for a file ending with js, css, jpeg, jpg, gif, png, bmp, ico.

Comment: images,js, now working fine but it doesn't pass uri to index.php !!! That's a big problem. :/

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]` Not working because RewriteEngine is off !!!

Comment: @stackminu Sorry, didn't mean to imply you want to get rid of the line turning on your rewrite engine. Just that you want to replace your `RewriteRule` lines with this.